# Checking if the linked list is circular

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

I was just reading about tortoise and hare (slow and fast runner) algorithm [here](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/data-structures/how-to-find-if-a-linked-list-is-circular-or-has-a-cycle-or-it-ends/), but I don't really understand why it's considered the best solution.

Wouldn't it be less time consuming to do this:

- save root node
- travel through the linked list
- at each new node, check if it's the root node.

Comment: No; a list which contains a circle may have the head node at the end of the tail of a 6 or 9; the head may not be on the circle, but the list is still circular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized a circular list doesn't necessarily need to be connecting back to its head. It can just have a loop somewhere in the middle. That makes 2 "runners" necessary.

But if you are checking explicitly for a "snake eating its own tail" kind of linked list, then it would be enough to just check for equality of the pointer with a root node, like I suggested before

Comment: Are you answering your own question or are you amending it with a refined question?  If the latter, please edit your question to include the refinement.

Comment: The "2 runners" method has the advantage of being more general purpose but your conclusions are correct.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy I did technically answer my own question

Comment: @tehawtness Thanks! Do you think it would it be better to have the "faster runner" skip 2 or 3 nodes at a time? I guess it depends on a size... The larger the guess, the more steps it should skip, correct?